# python/pandas : Pandas changing the value adding extra digits in values

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a csv file thru pandas which is like below -

```
Country, Longitude, Latitude
Netherland,48.436252,-124.068561
Netherland,48.436252,-124.068561
Netherland,48.436252,-124.068561
```

After doing the processing it is changing the values of Latitude for 2 of the rows like below.

```
Country, Longitude, Latitude
Netherland,48.436252,-124.068561
Netherland,48.436252,-124.06856100000002
Netherland,48.436252,-124.06856100000002
```

here is the read statement

```
input_file = pd.read_csv("country.csv",encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
```

I am not doing any processing related to longitude or latitude column. Not sure why is changing the values in two of rows and what I can do to fix it.

Comment: would this df['Latitude'].round(decimals=6) be acceptable?

Comment: I added this to fix the issue input_file = pd.read_csv("country.csv",encoding = 'ISO-8859-1',dtype = {'Latitude' : 'str', 'Longitude' : 'str'})

Comment: yes it works too